# ban and user activation system but I have some problems on the login script

Tags: php, pdo, login-script

I'm new to php. I have a login system, and now I'm trying to implement a ban and user activation system but I have some problems on the login script. Here is the code from my script:

```
 <?php
    $query = "SELECT id, username, password, salt, email, firstname, lastname, active, banned FROM users WHERE username = :username "; 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 
    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

    $login_ok = false; 
    $login_match = false; 
    $login_active = false; 
    $login_banned = false; 

    if($row) 
    { 
        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
        if($check_password === $row['password']) 
        { 
            $login_match = true; 
        } 
    if($row['active'] == 1) {
        $login_active = true;
    }
    if($row['banned'] == 1) {
        $login_banned = true;
    }
    if($login_match && $login_active && !$login_banned) {
        $login_ok = true;
    }
    } 
    if($login_ok) 
    { 
        unset($row['salt']); 
        unset($row['password']); 
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 
        header("Location: index.php"); 
        die("Redirecting..."); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        if(!$login_match) { echo "Wrong username/pasword.";}
        if(!$login_active) { echo "Account not activated, check your email";}
        if($login_banned) { echo "Your account is banned";}
    } 
?>
```

In my Database I have 2 columns active and banned, where 0 means that account is activated and not banned, and 1 if account is not activate or is banned.

How can I display different messages to the user? If a user will enter a wrong username or password, he will get all three messages from the final else {}. I want to display messages to the user like this:
If username or password is wrong, display only Wrong username/pasword. and ignore $login_active $login_banned.
If username/password is ok, but account not activated, Account not activated, check your email. and ignore the $login_banned switch.
If username/password is ok, but account is banned display Your account is banned and ignore the $login_active switch.

I'm sorry if I wrote too much, I hope I explained right.

Comment: `"=="` is a logic operator. 

`$login_active == true;`

so that doesn't make sense. try `$login_active = true;`

Comment: typo mistake here on site, I noticed after I posted my question but I don't know hot to edit

Comment: There is an edit option right under the tags of the post.

Comment: Evaluate the logic. You could use else statements, but would have to order them correctly.

Comment: i don't know how, give me a hint about the order, then i will write the code.

Comment: check the no of rows for a username, if exists then check others, if not,give wrong user name message. and try others the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
if(!$login_match) { echo "Wrong username/pasword.";}
if(!$login_active) { echo "Account not activated, check your email";}
if($login_banned) { echo "Your account is banned";}
```

To this:

```
<?php
if ($login_banned == true) {
        echo "Your account is banned";
} else if ($login_match != true) {
        echo "Wrong username/password.";
} else if ($login_active != true) {
        echo "Account not activated, check your email";
}
?>
```

I hope it does what you want.

Below are options you could still use:

```
//PICK OPTIONS DEPENDING ON YOUR PREFERENCE AND MESSAGE PRIORITIES
    //option 1
    if ($login_match != true) {
        echo "Wrong username/pasword.";
    } else if ($login_banned != true) {
        echo "Your account is banned";
    } else if ($login_active != true) {
        echo "Account not activated, check your email";
    }

    //option 2
    if ($login_match != true) {
        echo "Wrong username/pasword.";
    } else if ($login_active != true) {
        echo "Account not activated, check your email";
    } else if ($login_banned != true) {
        echo "Your account is banned";
    }

    //option 3
    if ($login_banned == true) {
        echo "Your account is banned";
    } else if ($login_match != true) {
        echo "Wrong username/password.";
    } else if ($login_active != true) {
        echo "Account not activated, check your email";
    }
```

Comment: I tried this. If I enter good user, bad password, and the account is not activated, I get the message "Account not activated, check your email" Instead of "Wrong username/password."

Comment: Depends on your preference. Since that's your preference, I've modified the code. Try it

Comment: Thank you very much. I now understand how to display my messages properly.

Comment: I've even added more options for you to try. Each option prioritizes a message above the other. So re-ordering them gives you control on what you want a user to see first if they fall under two more categories. If they fall under just one, they get the first matching message. If the fall under two or more, they get the high priority message.

Comment: I've used Option 1, but with $login_banned == true